# Kitchen installation plumbing and electricity preparation

Tags: electrical, kitchens

Hi when I install a new kitchen, should I first take care that the electric wires that are behind the base cabinets will be hidden inside the walls? Is it ok if they will be inside a plastic "tunnel" outside the wall?
The plastic tunnel outside the wall is shallow enough so it won't interfere with the cabinets (no need to cut the cabinets back walls)

[image: Here is the kitchen wall]

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure whether it meets code, but the key concern is that screws used to mount the base cabinets might damage the wiring. Just plan to avoid that.

Answer (score 2):

In the US the wiring just needs to be protected, normally by 1/2 inch plywood or Sheetrock. With that said the wiring is also required to be 1-1/4” back . If the wires are covered with conduit that would also work. ( not sure what you mean by tunnel).

Added:
With a closer look at the outlet you are not in the us so this may be ok your location would be helpful.

Comment: Thank you. I'm in Germany, I guess that by by "tunnel" I mean conduit. I'm not proficient with the terminology :). So what I have now is a rectangular, plastic, conduit that's about 1 Inch deep.

Comment: Over here with the electrical in conduit it would be fine hopefully one of our German users will see this and help. If you can wait I will add a bounty but the question needs to be open for a while to do that.

Comment: @Gil-Mor -- in IEC practice, what you're talking about is often called "trunking", and is equivalent to a North American "surface raceway" ("Wiremold" or such)

Comment: Three phase I do remember some overseas co workers using the term trunking. I looked but did not find if it needs to be accessible.